# Python web-scraper applied through Visual Studio question

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this web scraper program in python, but it prints both tennis players Felix and Alexander. I would like to only print the first available tennis player as a separate item and exclude all the ones after it, so what do I need change in the code to do this?

To note, I did this through Visual Studio 2022 and applied the program to use Microsoft Edge web browser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/atp-singles/basel/auger-aliassime-felix-bublik-alexander/U5HIueTc/")
webpage = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    values = [data for data in h2.find_all('a')]
    for value in values:
        print(value.text.replace(" ","_"))
    print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through each tag individually you can use the select() function to find that specific tag and print the first one.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/atp-singles/basel/auger-aliassime-felix-bublik-alexander/U5HIueTc/")
webpage = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

print(soup.select('h2 a')[0].text.replace(' ','_'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the loop, just do

```
print(soup.h2.text.strip())
```